# Javascript + Json array objects iterate into html using pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to render the HTML based on a JavaScript object. For each entry in the array I would like an anchor tag with the entry title, comma separator and the last one with "and" like in attachment image:

I am using Jade template:

```
- 
var data = {"msg": [
    {"title": "A", "link": "https://www.a.com/"}, 
    {"title": "B", "link": "http://www.b.com"}, 
    {"title": "B", "link": "https://www.c.com/"} 
] };

var lists = data.msg;
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
  a.(href=lists[i].link)=list[i].title 
  if(i>0 &&  lists.length != i-1) 
   | ,
  else if( lists.length == i-1)
   | and
```

Expected Output:

[image]

It;s not working as expected. Can you please anyone help me.

Sorry, I already asked a question like this, but in that question is unclear.

Comment: First of all lists.length == i , wont work, the right is lists.length-1 == i

Comment: thanks for notify, updated, but still it;s not working as expected

Comment: The easiest way to have a hint is to create a code snippet in order to show the problem. For example, I dont understand why you have on 'if(i>0 &&  lists.length != i-1) ' the i>0.

Comment: I want to add comma(,) for each element and in last element needs to add 'and'. please check the attachment for your reference.

Comment: So something like this should work : 
lists.map((elem, index) => {
    if( index === lists.length -2) {
       elem + 'and'
    }else if(index === lists.length -1){
       elem 
    }else {
       elem + ','
    }
})

Comment: @RSKMR looks like you edited in `i-1` when geo said `lists.length-1` and leave `i` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<div id="whatever">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function main(){
    var data = {"msg": [
        {"title": "A", "link": "https://www.a.com/"}, 
        {"title": "B", "link": "http://www.b.com"}, 
        {"title": "B", "link": "https://www.c.com/"} 
    ] };
    var tempHTML = "";
    for(var i=0;i<data.msg.length;i++){
        var thisLink = data.msg[i];
        tempHTML = tempHTML + '<a href="'+thisLink.link+'">'+thisLink.title+'</a>';
        if(i==data.msg.length-2){
            tempHTML = tempHTML + " and ";
        }
        else if(i!=data.msg.length-1){
            tempHTML = tempHTML + ", ";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("whatever").innerHTML = tempHTML;
}

main();
</script>
```